# Is is true that $ \exists~ \lim(a_n+b_n)~\text{and}~\exists~\lim a_n \Rightarrow \exists ~\lim b_n. $

Tags: real-analysis

I"m interested in knowing if the following affirmation is true
$$
\exists~\lim(a_n+b_n)~\text{and}~\exists~\lim a_n \Rightarrow \exists~\lim b_n.
$$
It *seems* true, and I tried to prove it using the definition, but I couldn't.

Comment: Let $x = lim (a_n + b_n)$ and $y = lim a_n$. Then, if $a_n + b_n$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of $x$, and $a_n$ is within $\epsilon/2$ from $y$, then $b_n = a_n + b_n - a_n$ is ... (use triangle inequality)

Answer (score 1):

let $lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=b$ and $lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=u$

$lim_{n \to \infty }b_n=b \Rightarrow lim_{n \to \infty }-b_n=-b$

$ lim_{n \to \infty }-b_n=-b$ and $lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=u$ $\Rightarrow lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n+(-b_n))=lim_{n \to \infty }-b_n+lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n+b_n)=u-b$

$lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=u-b$

Comment: I appreciate your effort but in this case one would normally use the definition of limit of a sequence